forcing to display null value if there is no record in the list
i would like to ask question regarding left join and group by since examples in documentation are more of the basic one, i am looking for a combine group by with where clause that fits the needs that i wish to display
my tables are
employee table
| emp_id | lastname | firstname |
+-------+-----------+-----------+
|  sgi01 | Doe      | John      |
|  sgi02 | Doe      | Karen     |  
|  sgi03 | Doe      | Vincent   |
|  sgi04 | Doe      | Kyle      | 
+--------+-------+--------------+

time_records table
| emp_id | date     |time_in  |time_out  |      
+--------+----------+---------|----------|
|  sgi01 |2024-03-01|07:00:00 |16:03:22  | 
|  sgi02 |2024-03-01|07:00:00 |16:03:22  |  
+--------+----------+---------+----------+

Result Table
| emp_id | lastname | firstname | time_in|time_out|Ctime_in   |Ctime_out  |number_of_hrs
+-------+-----------+-----------+--------+--------+-----------+-----------+-------------+
|  sgi01 | Doe      | John      |07:00:00+16:03:22|07:00:00 AM|04:03:22 PM|09:03:22
|  sgi02 | Doe      | Karen     |07:00:00+16:03:22|07:00:00 AM|04:03:22 PM|09:03:22    
+-------+-------+---------------+-------------------------------------------------------+

MYSQL CODE
SELECT e.emp_id, e.lastname, e.firstname, T.time_in, t.time_out ,

TIME_FORMAT(time_in, "%r") as Ctime_in,

TIME_FORMAT(time_out, "%r") as Ctime_out,

TIMEDIFF(time_out,time_in) as number_of_hrs

FROM `employees` as e LEFT JOIN time_records as t  on e.emp_id = t.emp_id
where t.date = '2024-03-01'
GROUP by e.emp_id;

Desired or want to display like this
| emp_id | lastname | firstname | time_in|time_out  |Ctime_in   |Ctime_out  |number_of_hrs
+-------+-----------+-----------+---------+---------+-----------+-----------+----------+
|  sgi01 | Doe      | John      |07:00:00 |16:03:22 |07:00:00 AM|04:03:22 PM|09:03:22
|  sgi02 | Doe      | Karen     |07:00:00 |16:03:22 |07:00:00 AM|04:03:22 PM|09:03:22   
|  sgi03 | Doe      | Vincent   |Null or 0|Null or 0|Null or 0  |Null or 0  |Null or 0|
|  sgi04 | Doe      | Kyle      |Null or 0|Null or 0|Null or 0  |Null or 0  |Null or 0|
+-------+-------+---------------+-------------------------------------------------------+

Normally i would just use group by and left join to force the other record to view as null but when i try to include a date range it gives me only the record that has data..

The problem is the other employees do not have record in  in time_records but you have this in your condition:
where t.date = '2024-03-01'

To include them even without records in time_records, change it to below:
where t.date = '2024-03-01' OR t.date IS NULL


thanks for the answer, didnt know it was possible to do conditional OR on where clause ..ill accpt your answer after 2 min
